# Find $f$ such that $\int_{x}^{f^{-1}(x)}f(t)dt=x^2.$

Tags: real-analysis

Find $f$ such that $\int_{x}^{f^{-1}(x)}f(t)dt=x^2$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}.$ Here $f$ is a bijection of $\mathbb{R}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and is differentiable with derivative not equal to $0.$

I tried to apply the fundamental theorem of calculus but I get $$x(f^{-1}(x))'-f(x)=2x.$$ But I am not being able to get rid of $f^{-1}(x)$ in order to get a differential equation in terms of $f(x).$ I know that $(f^{-1}(x))'=\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}$ But this does not help either.

Comment: is $f^{-1}(x)=1/f(x)$?

Comment: As he mentions, that $f$ is a bijection, I suppose $f^{-1}$ means the inverse

Comment: @Vasya No that is not true.

Comment: $$ F(f^{-1}(x))-F(x)=x^2 $$
$$ F(u)-F(f(u)) = f(u)^2 $$
$$ f(u) - f'(u) f(f(u)) = 2 f'(u) f(u) $$

Comment: Do you want all functions that satisfy this, or just one example?

Comment: I have written the exact problem statement so I don't know whether an example is needed or just a unique solution.

Answer (score 4):

Try this function: $f(x)=(-1+\sqrt{2})x$. I was looking for a solution in the form of $f(x)=cx$, then $f^{-1}(x)=\frac{x}{c}$ and  $\int_{x}^{f^{-1}(x)}f(t)dt=\int_{x}^{x/c}ct \:dt= \frac{c}{2}(\frac{x^2}{c^2}-x^2)=\frac{cx^2}{2}(\frac{1}{c^2}-1)=x^2$. Thus, we have an equation for $c$: $\frac{c(1-c^2)}{c^2}=2$, $1-c^2=2c$.